# Условное прижатие footer-а

Tags: css, вёрстка

Как сделать, чтобы футер приклеивался к низу страницы **только** если эта страница помещается по вертикали в окно браузера?

Comment: Почитайте: [как прижать футер (подвал) к низу](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/karkas-verstki/podval-k-nizu.html).

Comment: Я пользуюсь вот таким хаком [cssstickyfooter](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)

Comment: Не вижу смысла в переоткрытии, ответ уже есть в другом вопросе.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35320472#35320472. Дополнительное обоснование приведено чуть ниже: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35321223#35321223.